# Android Native browser doesn't respect z-index for scrolling

Tags: html, css, z-index, android-browser

I have setup a fiddle to reproduce this issue. Only in android native browser, the scroll is working for the element beneath absolute positioned element. It doesn't seem to respect the z-index for scrolling.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#scroll {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.overlay {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #333;
   opacity: .4;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 4;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;    
 }
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/s4vPV/5/

Result: http://fiddle.jshell.net/s4vPV/5/show/

Comment: try use z-index: -1; check your fiddle

Comment: @mcmac Nope. Expected o/p is Scroll should not happen. Only in android native browser (not chrome) scroll is happening for the div "#scroll".

Answer (score 2):

Give your `#scroll` div a `position:relative`, and set the `z-index:3` or something less, so that the browser respects what is on top of what.

Answer (score 2):

I made some minor changes to your CSS, which solved the issue you are running into:

On your `#scroll` element, you are not defining the positioning, but you are defining the position on your .overlay element with `absolute`. This, plus apply the `z-index` property with a value of 4 to the `.overlay` element causes the overlay to stack on top of the `#scroll` element. Since the overlay has a height and width of 100%, you are causing the `#scroll` element to become inaccessible, due to the `.overlay` element covering it entirely.

```
#scroll {
   height: 100%;
   overflow: scroll;
}

.overlay {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #333;
   opacity: .4;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 4;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
}
```

Basically, if the browser were sheets of paper that were perfectly stacked upon one another, you wouldn't be able to read "access" at the bottom of the stack.

If you are trying to style your scroll bars, I would recommend looking into styling them directly. If not, all you have to do is place a position: relative on the `#scroll` and a `z-index: 5;` which will solve this issue.

Here is a jsfiddle with the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/dmidify/s4vPV/10/